# How to add active class to first child element in React on load?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component called `ListElement` serves as navigation for my page. On click, I am adding `active` to `.listItem` in order to give it "active" styles. I have this working on click, but unsure on how I can add this class on page load?

The only way I can think of is to create a boolean `prop`, and then add the class based on if it's true, but this doesn't seem like the best way to go about it?

`ListItem.js`

```
import React from 'react';

function ListItem(props) {
  const label = props.label;
  return(
    <li className="listItem">
      <span className="listItem-label">{label}</span>
    </li>
  )
}

export default ListItem;
```

Which is included in `Navigation.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListItem from '../ListItem/ListItem';

class Navigation extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="navigation">
        <ul className="navigation__ul">
          <ListItem label="List item 1"/>
          <ListItem label="List item 2"/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navigation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is entirely fine.

In order to keep track of the current navigation item, use `useState` like:

```
// ListItem.js
function ListItem({ label, active, onClick }) {
  return(
    <li
      className={active ? 'listItem active' : 'listItem'}
      onClick={() => onClick(label)}
      <span className="listItem-label">{label}</span>
    </li>
  )
}


// Navigation.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ListItem from '../ListItem/ListItem';

const navEntries = [
  'List item 1',
  'List item 2'
];

function Navigation() {
  const [currentEntry, setCurrentEntry] = useState(navEntries[0]);

  function onClick(entry) {
     setCurrentEntry(entry);
  }

  return(
    <div className="navigation">
      <ul className="navigation__ul">
        {navEntries.map(entry => (
           <ListItem
             key={entry}
             label={entry}
             active={entry === currentEntry}
             onClick={onClick}/>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You may want to have a look at [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) in order not to reinvent the wheel though.